# Determination of probiotic regimen based upon genomic profile?

Tags: probiotics, genetics

I have been amazed at the accurate and pertinent results from some services such as [NutriHacker](https://www.nutrahacker.com) (via data from [23andMe.com](https://customercare.23andme.com/hc/en-us/articles/202907670-Accessing-your-Raw-Data) or [DNA.Ancestry.com](https://dna.ancestry.com/en/legal/us/faq#raw-1)). This has allowed me to take my nutritional supplementation certainty to a much higher level that has been corroborated medically.

One thing that I have traditionally observed, from my own experience, is that some probiotic bacteria and yeast have left me feeling ill and caused bowel problems. No one has been able to ascribe a why to this or what regimens would be best for my particular scenario.

This has led me to think: *are there studies that indicate that certain probiotics are better for individuals with certain genetic profiles?*

If anyone has seen such studies or know of such research, a sharing of this would be much appreciated.  I think having this information would lead to a much better overall level of health for many of us vs stabbing in the dark, which most doctors and nutritionists have recommended to me so far.

Comment: It would help to know what probiotics you are taking as not all the commonly available probiotics have been declared completely safe or beneficial medically.

Comment: @BenCannon I've used quite a number over the years and cannot enumerate them all, but none have yielded good results.  Most recently I've taken `bacillus coagulans` (5B) which seemed to do nothing. About a year ago, I took [this from GNC](http://cl.ly/1D2j3T2d251m) and became extremely ill about a week after taking it with serious GI complications and have had to be on a periodic PPI since. Obviously my goal here is to REMOVE the guesswork and find out if there are genetic markers that indicate successful regimen per alleles, even if I have to manually pour over appropriate studies.

Comment: What do you mean by genetic profile?

Comment: @GrahamChiu meaning the full genetic raw data provided by services like [23andMe.com](http://www.23andme.com) and [Ancestry.com](http://dna.ancestry.com). Eg, 23andMe.com allows you to not only [browse, but download your full raw genetic profile](https://customercare.23andme.com/hc/en-us/articles/202907670-Accessing-your-Raw-Data).

Comment: On first read the GNC supplement doesn't seem to contain anything not already native (nor does it specify the amount of each bacteria). People can have heightened immune responses to specific bacterial strains or they may spread and become pathogenic in rare cases. So you can probably cross reference with the strains of other supplements you've taken to narrow down the culprit (make sure you check those strain numbers as well). There is a lot more to the answer aside from the reputability of the claims and businesses, I'll see if I have time in the next couple of days if someone doesn't first.

Comment: http://scholar.google.com/scholar?q=%22personalized+probiotics%22

Comment: I highly doubt it, microbiome studies are still in their infancy, as is full genomic profiling. The thing you are asking about is in work, and the time horizon until it is available to the public is measured in decades (according to a lecture by one of the leading scientists in the area I recently attended).

Comment: Could you share who gave the lecture and some references to the current efforts @rumtscho? I'd be highly interested in digging into the details more fully.

Comment: It was Peer Bork, head of this group: http://www.embl.de/research/units/scb/bork/index.html and member of the IHMC. I have no further references.